# How to use awk to add the value of second lines of 2 csv files in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, awk

I am using ubuntu and we got a csv file1.csv with 2 columns looks like

```
a,1
b,1
...
```

and another file2.csv with 2 columns looks like

```
a,24324
b,432
```

The first column is the same and sorted in file1.csv and file2.csv. 
How to use awk to add the the value of second lines of 2 csv files in Ubuntu to get the result like this:

```
a,24325
b,433
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2+=a[$1]}1' file1.csv file2.csv
a,24325
b,433
```

We set the input and output field separator to `,`. Using `NR==FNR` construct, we load the file1.csv in to an array `a`. `next` allows us to work with first file. Once the file is loaded in memory, we move to the second file and just add the value from our array to second column.

This will print the output to STDOUT. You can redirect the output to another file.

Comment: Thx! And what if I want to compute (1-24324)/(1+24324) as the second column? "awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2= (a[$1] - $2) / (a[$1] + $2)}1' file1.csv file2.csv"??

Comment: @user3692521 Yes that is correct. Though you might want to put a check for division by zero.